# How to get latest records based on Batch ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

```
declare @tab table 
             (
                 BatchID INT,
                 Code VARCHAR(20),
                 CommType INT,
                 LastStatus VARCHAR(5),
                 SourceModiifedLastDate varchar(30)
             )

INSERT INTO @tab(BatchID, Code, CommType, LastStatus, SourceModiifedLastDate)
VALUES (1,  'A003-3', 3, 'I', '2013-06-17 21:28:01.827'),
       (2,  'A004-1', 1, 'I', '2014-06-17 21:28:01.827'),
       (6,  'A003-3', 3, 'U', '2015-06-17 21:28:01.827'),
       (9,  'A003-3', 3, 'D', '2015-06-17 21:28:01.827'),
       (11, 'A004-1', 3, 'D', '2013-06-17 21:28:01.827'),
       (12, 'A004-1', 1, 'I', '2015-06-17 21:28:01.827'),
       (16, 'A005-3', 3, 'I', '2011-06-17 21:28:01.827'),
       (19, 'A005-3', 3, 'D', '2013-0617 21:28:01.827'),
       (20, 'A006-3', 3, 'U', '2011-06-17 21:28:01.827'),
       (21, 'A006-3', 3, 'I', '2013-0617 21:28:01.827')

Select * from @tab
```

Here in my sample data I need to get only Laststatus = 'D' records based on latest BatchID.

For example if you see Code = 'A003-3' it got inserted, updated and deleted I need to get this record

If you see code = 'A004-1' it got inserted, deleted and inserted I don't need this record.

Output should be :

```
BatchID Code    CommType    LastStatus  SourceModiifedLastDate
---------------------------------------------------------------
 9      A003-3      3           D       2015-06-17 21:28:01.827
19      A005-3      3           D       2013-06-17 21:28:01.827
```

I need to get only latest deleted records based on latest `BatchID` and latest date.

I have tried using `MAX` condition and `GROUP BY` to filter records but I'm unable to get what I'm looking for.

Please help me find a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select tt.*
from (select t.*
           , row_number() over (partition by Code order by BatchId desc) as rn
      from @tab t
     ) tt
where tt.rn = 1 
  and tt.LastStatus = 'D';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using a CTE and filtering for only those BatchIds that have the last action as a delete

```
;
WITH CTE1 AS (  
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (partition by Code ORDER BY BatchID DESC ) [CodeRank]
    FROM @tab)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE1 
WHERE CodeRank = 1 and LastStatus = 'D'
```

Answer (score 0):

A typical way of doing tis uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by Code order by BatchId desc) as seqnum
      from @tab t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The old-fashioned way of doing it (before window functions) might look like this:

```
select t.*
from @tab t
where t.BatchId = (select max(t2.BatchId)
                   from @tab t2
                   where t2.Code = t.Code
                  );
```

Comment: It's not even close to giving any result ...complete wrong result set

Comment: see my answer and your problem statement is not clear

Comment: @gordon-linoff has made a mistake in using the BatchId rather than the Code. That's the issue with this answer.

Comment: @sam and using SourceModiifedLastDate - there are some ties

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT tab1.BatchId, tab1.Code, tab1.CommType, tab1.LastStatus, tab1.SourceModiifedLastDate
FROM @tab tab1
INNER JOIN  (
SELECT Code, MAX(SourceModiifedLastDate) MaxSourceModiifedLastDate
FROM @tab
GROUP BY Code) tab2
ON tab2.Code = tab1.Code
AND tab2.MaxSourceModiifedLastDate = tab1.SourceModiifedLastDate
WHERE tab1.LastStatus = 'D'
```